# Python not is for searching in List is not working

Tags: python, list, search

I am trying to create another graph from the given graph which has mutually exclusive edges.

I am randomly drawing nodes from the original graph and checking whether if it already exists in the original graph. The `not in` command not working as expected.

My code is following.

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import random
G=nx.karate_club_graph()
K=nx.Graph()
sample_len=len(G.edges())
while(len(K.edges())<sample_len):
    n1=random.choice(G.nodes())
    n2=random.choice(G.nodes())
    e=(n1,n2)
    if(e not in G.edges()):
        K.add_edge(*e)
i=0
for x in G.edges():
    if(x in K.edges()):
        i+=1
print i
```

Every time I run this code the value of `i` is in between 5-10.

Comment: what are u expecting as result?

Comment: I am checking common edges between two graphs. The answer should be zero.

Comment: if u send me an example of G=nx.karate_club_graph()
K=nx.Graph() I'll try to get it for you, I don't think that it's difficult but it's long time that I don't use numpy library and just reading the code I can't help sorry!

Comment: G=nx.karate_club_graph() is inbuilt graph dataset in networkx and K=nx.Graph() is an empty graph I am intializing.

Comment: If you inspect actual values of e and x, are they the same type and format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Graph.has_edge()`:

```
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import random
G=nx.karate_club_graph()
K=nx.Graph()
sample_len=len(G.edges())
while(len(K.edges())<sample_len):
    n1=random.choice(G.nodes())
    n2=random.choice(G.nodes())
    e=(n1,n2)
    if(not G.has_edge(*e)):
        K.add_edge(*e)
i=0
for x in G.edges():
    if(K.has_edge(*x)):
        i+=1
print(i)
```

The problem is probably because networkx stores the edges differently than you expect. For an undirected graph either `(n1, n2)` or `(n2, n1)` would valid. Therefore the following check would also solve your problem but is obviously more verbose than using `has_edge()`:

```
if((n1, n2) not in G.edges() and (n2, n1) not in G.edges()):
    K.add_edge(n1, n2)
```

Comment: G.has_edge() is working. Thanks. Still, couldn't understand the what is wrong with `not in`.

Comment: See my description above. I believe it may be possible that networkx stores the edges differently. E.g. `G` contains an edge `(1, 2)`. Then you check if edge `(2, 1)` exists. It does not and you add it to `K`. Later you search for edge `(1, 2)` in graph `K`. It's possible that `K` stores the edge `(2, 1)` as `(1, 2)` and it would therefore be found. This all assumes that the graphs are undirected.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the difference you can do in this way:

```
print (list(set(G.edges()) - set(K.edges())))
```

if you want just a number add len

```
print (len(list(set(G.edges()) - set(K.edges()))))
```

Please let me know if it's this what you are trying to archive ;)